# Can I protect here.com API KEY by dns or ip like I was doing with APP CODE?

Tags: here-api

Here.com says that "APP CODE credentials will no longer be provided for new projects" ([here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/index.html)). We need to use the API KEY instead, but with old APP CODE there was an option to "create a trusted domain for your app credentials". This feature does not exist today with API KEY. How can I protect my API KEY by dns or ip, knowing I access the API by REST from a Python script on a server and not in JS ???

**Note** : on new here.com accounts there is no possibility to create a JS REST key, only REST is available.

Here is my interface : [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can protect the APIKEY by assigning it to a trusted domain, just like your APP ID APP CODE.
Head over to your project page and create a JS APIKEY. You will then get an option to assign it to a trusted domain.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Shruti but I updated my post with a screenshot of Here's interface : this option does not exist anymore on my account !

Comment: Your screenshot shows the REST key and the Token. You need to create a JS APIKEY. The trusted domain option is under the JS key section.

Comment: Yes, on old Here accounts you have the possibility to create JS REST keys but if you create an account today, you will see that there is no way to create a JS REST, only REST is available !

Comment: I can see `JS` section above `REST` section (which is above old `JS REST` section). There I can see the whitelisting option:
https://prnt.sc/vth9gd

Comment: But I need the REST API, not the JS API (to access API from my serveur)

Comment: you can use the JS key for both.